# FTP'd Text file using Python 3 is empty

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

I am trying to FTP a file from a windows box running python 3.3 to a linux box running Ubuntu 12.04.

I have been able to FTP the file, but the file on the remote server is always empty even though the local file has about 8k in it. Its a small text file.

I have tried a few suggestions from both Google and the SE network. All the different tests are commented out. Those have failed with various errors and/or similar results as the uncommented one. (0 byte file)

I also read in the txt file to ensure I was FTPing the right file.

Code is below. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
filename = 'Music.txt'


#write data to file
file = open('Music.txt', 'w+')
for music in musicList:
    file.write(music+'\n')

file.close()

localfile = open(filename, 'r')
#print(localfile)
#for line in localfile:
#    print(line)


#ftp file to webserver for consumption
ftp = FTP(host) # connect to host webdev (local)
ftp.login(username, password)
print(ftp.getwelcome())
ftp.cwd('projects/home/musicCat/data')

ftp.retrbinary("RETR Music.txt", localfile.write)
#ftp.storlines("STOR Music.txt", open('Music.txt'))
#ftp.storbinary("STOR Music.txt", localfile.write)
#ftp.storbinary("STOR Music.txt", file(file, "rb"))
#ftp.storbinary('STOR' + localfile.name, open(file.name, 'wb').write)
#ftp.storlines("STOR Music.txt", open(localfile, 'r'))
#ftp.storlines('STOR Music.txt', file)
print(ftp.retrlines('LIST'))
ftp.quit()
```

Interpreter Output:

```
220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
-rw-r--r--    1 1000     1000            0 Dec 27 21:14 Music.txt
226 Directory send OK.
>>>
```

BUMP: Anyone have any ideas? I have yet to be able to successfully transfer the file via ftp. I'm debating about using python 2.7 and paramiko.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you're looking for a cross-platform pure python approach, but sometimes it's easiest to just use python to execute an external utility via `subprocess.call()`
http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html

I had similar issues establishing a SSH tunnel from Windows, and really did not want to switch to 2.7 to use paramiko. I ended up just calling plink.exe from my script.

For ftp on Windows, you can use the built-in utility **`ftp`**

```
Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
(sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.

FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] [-s:filename] [-a] [-A] [-x:sendbuffer] [-r:recvbuffer] [-b:asyncbuffers] [-w:windowsize] [host]

  -v              Suppresses display of remote server responses.
  -n              Suppresses auto-login upon initial connection.
  -i              Turns off interactive prompting during multiple file
                  transfers.
  -d              Enables debugging.
  -g              Disables filename globbing (see GLOB command).
  -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
                  commands will automatically run after FTP starts.
  -a              Use any local interface when binding data connection.
  -A              login as anonymous.
  -x:send sockbuf Overrides the default SO_SNDBUF size of 8192.
  -r:recv sockbuf Overrides the default SO_RCVBUF size of 8192.
  -b:async count  Overrides the default async count of 3
  -w:windowsize   Overrides the default transfer buffer size of 65535.
  host            Specifies the host name or IP address of the remote
                  host to connect to.

Notes:
  - mget and mput commands take y/n/q for yes/no/quit.
  - Use Control-C to abort commands.
```

Comment: I'm still trying to do this all in python if possible. But as time passes I may have to go with a different approach, either 2.7 and paramiko or your suggestion plink.

Comment: I ended up just posting data to and endpoint and the endpoint had access to the server via php and was able to save the data. Moving forward, I plan to user your approach detailed above where you call an os specific program to handle the ftp transfer.